# angular $resource does not behave the way expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have this angular code

```
angular.module('ninthBeatApp')
  .factory('Item', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/items/:id', {
        id: '@_id'
    });
  });

angular.module('ninthBeatApp')
  .controller('ItemCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Item) {
    $scope.item = Item.get({ _id: $stateParams.id });
  });
```

In the backend, I got
`GET /api/items?_id=550b3d2b532f415ce5080056 304 27ms`
this is not what I want.

It supposed to be
`GET /api/items/550b3d2b532f415ce5080056`

Anyone knows why?

Comment: try this $scope.item = Item.get({  $stateParams.id });

Comment: that wont work, because there is no syntax such as { $stateParams.id}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$scope.item = Item.get({id: $stateParams.id});
```

This will plug the $stateParams value into the url directly instead of passing it as a GET query param. The `@_id` refers to how a [default parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage) is determined.

Comment: yeah thats what I did. however, later in the future I want to do something like Item.put(itemObj) where itemObj will have _id parameters.  I dont want to change _id to id just to do that.  based on my understanding, id: @_id will read the _id parameter and put it to id.